# jQuery UI Tabs - How to Get Currently Selected Tab Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I know this specific question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185235/jquery-tabs-getting-newly-selected-index), but I am not getting any results using the `bind()` event on the `jQuery UI Tabs` plugin.

I just need the `index` of the newly selected tab to perform an action when the tab is clicked. `bind()` allows me to hook into the select event, but my usual method of getting the currently selected tab does not work. It returns the previously selected tab index, not the new one:

```
var selectedTab = $("#TabList").tabs().data("selected.tabs");
```

Here is the code I am attempting to use to get the currently selected tab:

```
$("#TabList").bind("tabsselect", function(event, ui) {

});
```

**When I use this code, the ui object comes back `undefined`**. From the documentation, this should be the object I'm using to hook into the newly selected index using ui.tab. I have tried this on the initial `tabs()` call and also on its own. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**For JQuery UI versions before 1.9**: `ui.index` from the `event` is what you want.

**For JQuery UI 1.9 or later**: see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973370/2333214) by Giorgio Luparia, below.

Comment: Very nice answer!  I included a summary of what you did in the website just to make it easier to get the answer.

Comment: Cheers, the Q mentioned the ui object was null, therefore ui.index will fail at present. I think the answer maybe not so simple as including that.

Comment: This was a perfect answer, and thanks for the awesome example! I was trying to do everything in 1 shot, and it wasn't working. After I split it out, everything worked as advertised.

Comment: That's great... your link doesn't work anymore.  Why don't you just post the answer so people to come can see the solution as well.

Comment: The answer is there - use ui.index property to get the current index in the tabselect event.....

Comment: I don't quite understand.  How do I get the currently selected tab? $('.selector').tabs('option', 'ui.index') doesn't work because it isn't an option.

Comment: @Patrick Szalapski $('#TabContainer').tabs("option", "selected");

Comment: @redsquare, that doesn't work--it only gives me the "default" selected tab, not the dynamically changing selected tab.

Comment: can you knock up a demo at jsfiddle.  $('#TabContainer').tabs("option", "selected"); should give you the current selected tab

Comment: Answer should be updated because it's not working with JQuery UI 1.9.0. You should change ui.index with ui.newTab.index() according to the Upgrade Guide (http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-select-event-renamed-to-beforeactivate)

Comment: @Giorgio Luparia why? Can you imagine everybody having to update their answers for every new release of every framework.....the real issue is questions not being tagged with versions

Comment: @redsquare I already submitted an edit for peer review. I'd find it useful to have a general answer saying: for versions below 1.9.0 do this, for versions above do that. But maybe I'm not following a good practice. Should I submit and answer a new identical question/answer, tagged with versions?

Comment: @Giorgio Luparia you could do yeah - versioning is something SO needs to sort out - instead the mods would rather close questions all day!!

Answer (score 206):

If you need to get the tab index from outside the context of a tabs event, use this:

```
function getSelectedTabIndex() { 
    return $("#TabList").tabs('option', 'selected');
}
```

Update:
From version 1.9 'selected' is changed to 'active'

```
$("#TabList").tabs('option', 'active')
```

Comment: That appeared to be what I needed, anyway.

Comment: Looks like this actually gives the default tab, not the currently selected tab.  What am I missing?  42 votes can't be wrong, can they?  http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected

Comment: The 'selected' option has been renamed to 'active' in jQuery UI version 1.9 (see http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.9.0)

Answer (score 45):

If you're using JQuery UI version 1.9.0 or above, you can access **ui.newTab.index()** inside your function and get what you need.

For earlier versions use **ui.index**.

Comment: It would be great if you could flesh out your answer with some additional detail.

Answer (score 43):

> **UPDATE** [<sub>Sun 08/26/2012</sub>] This answer has become so popular that I decided to make it into a full-fledged blog/tutorial
>   
> Please visit [My Blog Here](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/08/jqueryjqueryui-help-tabs-get-currently.html) to see the latest in easy access information to working with *tabs* in jQueryUI
>   
> Also included (in the blog too) is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/vAggn/)

---

¡¡¡  Update! Please note: In newer versions of jQueryUI (1.9+), `ui-tabs-selected` has been replaced with `ui-tabs-active`. !!!

---

*<strike>I know this thread is old, but</strike>* something I didn't see mentioned was how to get the "selected tab" (Currently dropped down panel) from somewhere other than the "tab events".
I do have a simply way ...

```
var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)');
```

And to easily get the index, of course there is the way listed on the site ...

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // => 0
```

However, you could use my first method to get the index and anything you want about that panel pretty easy ...

```
var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)'),
    curTabIndex = curTab.index(),
    curTabID = curTab.prop("id"),
    curTabCls = curTab.attr("class");
        //  etc ....
```

PS. If you use an iframe variable then .find('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)'), you will find it easy to do this for selected tabs in frames as well.
Remember, jQuery already did all the hard work, no need to reinvent the wheel!

> Just to expand (updated)

Question was brought up to me, "What if there are more than one tabs areas on the view?"
Again, just think simple, use my same setup but use an ID to identify which tabs you want to get hold of.

For example, if you have:

```
$('#example-1').tabs();
$('#example-2').tabs();
```

And you want the current panel of the second tab set:

```
var curTabPanel = $('#example-2 .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)');
```

And if you want the ACTUAL tab and not the panel (really easy, which is why I ddn't mention it before but I suppose I will now, just to be thorough)

```
// for page with only one set of tabs
var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-selected'); // '.ui-tabs-active' in jQuery 1.9+

// for page with multiple sets of tabs
var curTab2 = $('#example-2 .ui-tabs-selected'); // '.ui-tabs-active' in jQuery 1.9+
```

Again, remember, jQuery did all the hard work, don't think so hard.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! If you want you could also provide this as an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1864219/11992.

Comment: The 'selected' option has been renamed to 'active' in jQuery UI version 1.9 (see jqueryui.com/changelog/1.9.0).

Answer (score 14):

```js
var $tabs = $('#tabs-menu').tabs();
// jquery ui 1.8
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
// jquery ui 1.9+
var active = $tabs.tabs('option', 'active');
```

Answer (score 12):

When are you trying to access the ui object? ui will be undefined if you try to access it outside of the bind event.
Also, if this line

```
var selectedTab = $("#TabList").tabs().data("selected.tabs");
```

is ran in the event like this:

```
$("#TabList").bind("tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
  var selectedTab = $("#TabList").tabs().data("selected.tabs");
});
```

selectedTab will equal the current tab at that point in time (the "previous" one.)  This is because the "tabsselect" event is called before the clicked tab becomes the current tab.  If you still want to do it this way, using "tabsshow" instead will result in selectedTab equaling the clicked tab.

However, that seems over-complex if all you want is the index.  ui.index from within the event or $("#TabList").tabs().data("selected.tabs") outside of the event should be all that you need.

Comment: @Ben : your solution gives the previous selected tab as that was the index when the tabsselect event was triggered.

Comment: @Michael: Did you read my answer or just grab the code?  In my answer I state that the code will not work as is and provide a few alternatives ('tabshow' event; ui.index; $('TabList').tabs().data('selected.tabs'))

Comment: ： Sorry about my late response. Yeah, the ui.index works just fine. I just wanted to point out the fact that selected.tabs gives the "previous" selected tab, not the cureent one. I mean no offense to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

this changed with version 1.9

something like

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabs').tabs({
                activate: function (event, ui) {
                    var act = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");
                    $("#<%= hidLastTab.ClientID %>").val(act);
                    //console.log($(ui.newTab));
                    //console.log($(ui.oldTab));
                }
            });

            if ($("#<%= hidLastTab.ClientID %>").val() != "") 
            {
                $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", $("#<%= hidLastTab.ClientID %>").val());
            }


        });
```

should be used. This is working fine for me ;-)

Answer (score 5):

In case anybody has tried to access tabs from within an iframe, you may notice it's not possible. The `div` of the tab never gets marked as selected, just as hidden or not hidden. The link itself is the only piece marked as selected.

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-state-focus"><a href="#tabs-4">Tab 5</a></li>
```

The following will get you the `href` value of the link which should be the same as the id for your tab container:

```
jQuery('.ui-tabs-selected a',window.parent.document).attr('href')
```

This should also work in place of: `$tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');`

It's better in the sense that instead of just getting the index of the tab, it gives you the actual id of the tab.

Answer (score 5):

the easiest way of doing this is

```
$("#tabs div[aria-hidden='false']");
```

and for index

```
$("#tabs div[aria-hidden='false']").index();
```

Answer (score 4):

In case if you find Active tab Index and then point to Active Tab

First get the Active index

```
var activeIndex = $("#panel").tabs('option', 'active');
```

Then using the css class get the tab content panel

```
// this will return the html element
var element=   $("#panel").find( ".ui-tabs-panel" )[activeIndex];
```

now wrapped it in jQuery object to further use it

```
 var tabContent$ = $(element);
```

here i want to add two info the class `.ui-tabs-nav` is for Navigation associated with  and `.ui-tabs-panel` is associated with tab content panel. in this link demo in jquery ui website you will see this class is used - http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation

Answer (score 4):

I found the code below does the trick. Sets a variable of the newly selected tab index

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (e, ui) {
        currentTabIndex =ui.newTab.index().toString();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active" )
```

then you will have the index of tab from 0

simple

Answer (score 3):

You can post below answer in your next post

```
var selectedTabIndex= $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');
```

Comment: This answer is useful to find the current active tab, particularly when not in the context of a tab selection event.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs-menu').tabs();

var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');

var divAssocAtual = $('#tabs-menu ul li').tabs()[selected].hash;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find it via:

```
$(yourEl).tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.newPanel.index());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the selected tab index is:

```
var index = jQuery('#tabs').data('tabs').options.selected;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#tabs").tabs({  
    load:  function(event, ui){  
        var anchor = ui.tab.find(".ui-tabs-anchor");  
        var url = anchor.attr('href');  
    }  
});
```

In the **url** variable you will get the current tab's HREF / URL

Answer (score 0):

take a hidden variable like `'<input type="hidden" id="sel_tab" name="sel_tab" value="" />'` and on each tab's onclick event write code like ...

```
<li><a href="#tabs-0" onclick="document.getElementById('sel_tab').value=0;" >TAB -1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="document.getElementById('sel_tab').value=1;" >TAB -2</a></li>
```

you can get the value of 'sel_tab' on posted page. :) , simple !!!

Comment: I did not vote you down, but there is no reason for the extra markup and inline JavaScript. Especially since he is already using jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure `ui.newTab.index()` is available in all situations (local and remote tabs), then call it in the **activate** function as the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) says:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui){
             alert(ui.newTab.index());
             // You can also use this to set another tab, see fiddle...
             // $("#other-tabs").tabs("option", "active", ui.newTab.index());                   
        },
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7v7n0v3j/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        new_index = ui.newTab.index()+1;
        //do anything
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)