# Need currently selected tab ID for jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I know I can get the index of the currently selected tab but can I somehow get to the ID (the equivalent of the `ui.panel.id` if this were triggered by an tab event...but it's not) of the currently selected tab?  I'd prefer not to use the index because ordering of the tabs might change.  I prefer not to use the style markups as those may change in future releases.  Is there a method for this?  If not, can I somehow use the index to access this (maybe even by accessing the panel object first)? Any other ideas?

Comment: A variation of the question would be: Is there a way to get the tab panel from the index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery ui tabs: get the id of the tab (div) being activated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864219/need-currently-selected-tab-id-for-jquery-tabs)

Answer (score 25):

You can use the [`:visible` pseudo-selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to target the visible panel:

```js
$("#tabs .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id");
```

It's worth noting that you can retrieve the active tab from the [*activate* event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate):

```js
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.newPanel[0].id);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's pretty goofy.  What if you have multiple tab widgets on a page, for instance?

Comment: Then you give a more specific selector. `$("#group1 .ui-state-active")`.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. Instead I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7967944/11992

Comment: this gets the tab element not the container

Answer (score 13):

Jonathan Sampson's answer doesn't work anymore. Try...

`$("#tabs .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id");`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbEq6/

Answer (score 4):

If you want the `id` (or actually the `href`) from the selected tab, you can use `eq()` to retrieve the jQuery Object.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/svierkant/hpU3T/1/

Answer (score 3):

As I posted in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index/7967944#7967944), there are several ways to achieve this.

On the [jQuery documents](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...retrieve_the_index_of_the_currently_selected_tab), they propose to do the following to find the index of the currently open tab:

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // => 0
```

However, this is impractical if you need to do a lot with that tab.
Why they don't yet provide a more practical solution of getting the actual element, I'm unsure, however, through use of jQuery there is an easy solution you can create yourself.

In the following code i'll show you just how easy it is to do anything you want with the current tab:

```
var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)'),
    curTabIndex = curTab.index(),  //  will get you the index number of where it sits
    curTabID = curTab.prop("id"),  //  will give you the id of the tab open if existant
    curTabCls = curTab.attr("class");  //  will give you an array of classes on this tab
        //  etc ....
//    now, if you wanted a little more depth, for instance specific tabs area (if you have multiple tabs on your page) you can do simply add to your selector statement
var curTab = $('#myTabs_1 .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)');
//    then you can make simple calls to that tab and get whatever data or manipulate it how you please
curTab.css("background-color", "#FFF");
```

Answer (score 3):

After JQuery 1.9 selected is deprecated

So use

`var active = $( "#jtabs" ).tabs( "option", "active" );`

Answer (score 1):

For jquery version below 1.9:

```
 <div class="roundedFloatmenu">
        <ul id="unid">
            <li class="titleHover" id="li_search">Search</li>               
            <li class="titleHover" id="li_notes">Notes</li>
             <li class="titleHover active" id="li_writeback">Writeback</li>         
            <li class="titleHover" id="li_attorney">Attorney</li>
        </ul>
    </div
```

And you can find the active tab using:

```
 jQuery('#unid').find('li.active').attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var curTab = $jQuery('#tabs .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('#divName .ui-tabs-panel[aria-hidden="false"]').prop('id');
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery UI >= 1.9 you can use `ui.newPanel.selector`:

```
$('#tabs').on('tabactivate', function(event, ui) {
  console.log(ui.newPanel.selector);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I knocked my head against this wall for a while. I have a number of tabs that reference urls mixed in with a bunch of tabs that are populated by javascript code and, therefore, have associated divs (.ui-tabs-panel) that are defined in the markup.

jQuery UI Tabs Widget links tabs with panels using the "aria-labeledby" property of the panel. That property has a value of the anchor contained in the tab. So, for this markup

```
<ul><li id='tab_1'><a href='ferndorf.php'>I Be Tab_1</a></li></ul>
```

After attaching the jQuery Tab Widget, you can find the appropriate panel using

```
panel = $( '.ui-tab-panel[aria-labeledby=' + $( '#tab_1 a' ).attr( 'id' ) + ']' )
```

vice-versa, you can find the tab associated with the panel using

```
tab = $( '#' + $( panel ).attr( 'aria-labeledby' ) ).closest( 'li' );
```

The index of tabs and panels is only related in simple structures.

Have fun.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#tabs .ui-state-active a").attr("id");
```