# How get index of a selected tab?

Tags: jquery

Suppose to have a tab with 3 choices ("home","dog",house"). My purpose is to get the current selected element Anyone can help me?
I do this:

```
var r=$('#tab_sezioni ul li');
```

But in this way I take all tag

while I need to get the index of curentent select element of tab.

Comment: How do markup looks?

Comment: Can we see any code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864219/need-currently-selected-tab-id-for-jquery-tabs and if that answers the question then please delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a class so you can tell which tab is selected.
For example when you click on a tab add class `selected`.

```
     $('#tab_sezioni ul li').click(function(){
     $('#tab_sezioni ul li').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
     });
```

And then get only selected element

```
     var r=$('#tab_sezioni ul li.selected');
```

Or if you want just the index

```
    var index=$('#tab_sezioni ul li').index($('#tab_sezioni ul li.selected'));
```