# jQuery : how to get id of current activated tab

Tags: jquery, html

I have some tabs as below

I need to get the id of currently activated tab, and  i tried so many ways , still no luck ,

```
1. $('ul#apptabs li a').find('active').attr('id')
2. $('ul#apptabs li a.active').attr('id')
3. $('ul#apptabs nav-item').find('a.active').attr('id')
```

Snippet:

```js
console.log(
  $('ul#apptabs li a').find('active').attr('id'),
  $('ul#apptabs li a.active').attr('id'),
  $('ul#apptabs nav-item').find('a.active').attr('id')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="apptabs" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" style="margin:0px">
  <li id="map_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_1">Map</a>
  </li>
  <li id="feature_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_3">Feature</a>
  </li>
  <li id="analysis" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_4">Analysis</a>
  </li>
  <li id="editing_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_5">Editing</a>
  </li>
  <li id="general_div" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_6">General</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not a duplicate question ,this answer will not fit to my need , i tried that already . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864219/need-currently-selected-tab-id-for-jquery-tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to return to the parent node

```js
console.log($('ul#apptabs li a.active').parent().attr('id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="apptabs" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" style="margin:0px">
  <li id="map_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_1">Map</a>
  </li>
  <li id="feature_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_3">Feature</a>
  </li>
  <li id="analysis" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_4">Analysis</a>
  </li>
  <li id="editing_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_5">Editing</a>
  </li>
  <li id="general_div" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_6">General</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope that I get your question right.

You want the `id` of the `<li>` right?

The active state is however on the `<a>`, which is a child of the `<li>`. So you need to travel up the DOM tree to find the list-item. You can do that with `closest()`.

```js
console.log(
  $('ul#apptabs li a.active').closest('li').attr('id')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="apptabs" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" style="margin:0px">
  <li id="map_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_1">Map</a>
  </li>
  <li id="feature_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_3">Feature</a>
  </li>
  <li id="analysis" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_4">Analysis</a>
  </li>
  <li id="editing_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_5">Editing</a>
  </li>
  <li id="general_div" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_6">General</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or an alternative:

```
$('ul#apptabs li').has('a.active').attr('id')
```

```js
console.log(
  $('ul#apptabs li').has('a.active').attr('id')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="apptabs" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" style="margin:0px">
  <li id="map_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_1">Map</a>
  </li>
  <li id="feature_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_3">Feature</a>
  </li>
  <li id="analysis" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_4">Analysis</a>
  </li>
  <li id="editing_control" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_5">Editing</a>
  </li>
  <li id="general_div" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#m_tabs_1_6">General</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would advice `.parent()` on this one since we already know that the current element is an `<a>`.

Comment: You are right Ron, in this specific case. It may be noted that when the OP adds an extra element, `parent()` won't work, but `closest()` will.