# How to check which tab-pane is active

Tags: javascript, tabs, haml

I have created a tab-pane using HAML as shown in my code snippet below (2 tabs)

```
//tabs
tab-content
  .muses.active.tab-pane
    .muse_header
      %h3
    %ul.muses
    .center
      %button.btn#get_more_answers.hide Fetching Content
  .questions.tab-pane
    .question_header
      %h3
    %ul.questions
```

[image]

As shown above I have 2 tabs (.muses.active.tab-pane and questions.tab-pane)

Now I need to specify certain actions depending on which tab is active. How can I write the if statement to determine which tab-pane is active at one point of time?

Comment: Posible answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery framework, you can find the active tab using following command,
`$('.active.tab-pane')`

You can check if the active tab is a muse or question by checking against the class of that tab as follows,

```
if($('.active.tab-pane').hasClass('muses')){
  alert("its muses tab");
} else if($('.active.tab-pane').hasClass('questions')){
  alert("its questions tab");
}
```