# How to get current tab title which i named in Jquery Tabs UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation. I want to get an title of current selected tab which I earlier named (e.g. from a href). How to get it?

I tried:
`$(ui.tab).attr('href')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the jquery [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Events),

```
var selectedTabTitle = null;
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) {
            selectedTabTitle = $(ui.tab).text();
            alert(selectedTabTitle);
    }
});
```

Comment: Came across this by accident, just a note to future readers, there is a long post about this kind of thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index/7967944#7967944)

Comment: As of JQuery UI 1.9+, you need to use ui.newTab, i.e:

`selectedTabTitle = $(ui.newTab).text();`

Answer (score 17):

Alternative way to get tab title:

```
var selected = $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "selected" );
var selectedTabTitle = $($("#tabs li")[selected]).text();
```

Comment: chessBoard.js:91 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function

How can this possibly work?  What is this element with id "tabs"?

Answer (score 5):

Use following in case of jQuery 1.9+,

```
var currentTabTitle = $('div[id="mytabs"] ul .ui-tabs-active > a').attr("href");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just another version:

```
$("#tabsId .ui-state-active > a").html()
```

Answer (score 3):

i guess jquery was modified because now i was able to fetch tab name using:

```
$(function () {
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    activate : function (event,ui) {
        selectedTabTitle = ui.newTab[0].innerText;
        alert(selectedTabTitle);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I was struggling with this code.

Now I've used thiscode in my program. Working like this.

```
$('#tabs').click('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
    var selectedTab = $("#tabs").tabs('option','selected');
    alert("selectedTab===>" +  $($("#tabs li")[selectedTab]).text());
});
```