# ".selector " in api documentation of jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I am using jquery ui tabs and it works perfectly.Heres the code for jquery-ui tabs

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Suddenly i came across a scenario where i had to find the index of current active tab.So i went through the [Api Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) and find out the below code.

```
Get or set the active option, after initialization:
// getter
var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
// setter
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

What is ".selector " here and how can i get the current index of the active tab active tab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.selector` is the element upon which you invoked `tabs()`, so if your first code snippet is from your code, you need to replace `.selector` with `#tabs`.

For example:

```
var active = $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active");
```

Comment: I have written the above code in the jquery function but iam not getting the desired result.

Comment: What selector did you use to invoke the tabs in the first place?

Comment: I am sorry for troubling you.I got the result now.The mistake was i was using jquery version 1.8.3.In that case we should replace active with selected.Now i have changed to the jquery version 1.10.1 and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some of the documentation on the Jquery UI Tabs - I haven't worked with them much...

[jQuery UI Documentation (Tabs)](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#method-select)

It would possibly be something like

```
.tabs( "select" , index )
```

or

```
$('#nameOftabs').tabs({ selected: index });
```

Where index would be the default tab that you would like selected.

More answers

[answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960950/how-to-get-current-tab-title-which-i-named-in-jquery-tabs-ui)
[answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you answer1 helped me understand where i have gone wrong.