# Using a jQuery-Selector in the currently selected jQuery-UI Tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm currently working with jQuery-Tabs to simulate a multi-window inputmask. Thus the tabs are variable and users are allowed to add and remove them and the content in those tabs is always the same input-form.

Now I need to select via jQuery some of those fields. The problem is, that I would need to find out which tab is currently selected and use this info in the selector.

Is there a way to identify the currently selected Tab and use this info in a jQuery selector so I can manipulate the right fields?

Iterating through the tabs and checking properties like 'hidden' is not really an option, because it slows down the application significantly.

Comment: Checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index

Answer (score 0):

Write something like this:

```
var activeTab=0;

$(function(){
    $( ".selector" ).tabs({
       select: function(event, ui) { activeTab=ui.index; }
    });
});
```

and use `activeTab` variable wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

Look for the class called "ui-state-active" this will help you to find the active tab

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have the tab container as `#myTabs`

you can get the id of the selected div using

```
var id = $("li.ui-tabs-selected a", "#myTabs").attr("href"); // has # as part of the href
$(".myformelement", id).val();
```