# Trigger a function when a jQuery UI tab is clicked/made active?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, post, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery tabs and the content in one of the tabs is retrieved via an AJAX call. But I don't want to trigger the call until the tab is clicked (made active) because the user might not necessarily click it. What's the best way to do this?

jQuery UI provides `select` and `show` events for the tabs, but these fire when *any* tab is selected or shown, not just a specific one (as far as I know).

I've also tried assigning a `click` event to the specific tab's ID:

```
$("#my-tab").click(function(){
...
     $.post(URL, function(data){
          ...
     });
...
}
```

But this seemingly has no effect and the call is never triggered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ui-tabs provide a function which is triggered when you select a tab.

```
$( ".yourTab" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.index == myTabIndex) {
            $.post(URL, function(data){
              ...
            });
        }
   }
});
```

**Note** Use `activate` for new versions.

[reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)

Comment: Worked perfectly! I wasn't aware of how to use `select` for just a specific tab. Thanks!

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann this works great, but I do not see the select: object in the documentation, was looking there before I found this.

Comment: @Popo I think it has been replaced with `activate`.

Answer (score 17):

The ticked solution doesn't work any more because [jquery-ui has changed](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/tabs/). Also you need to call the tabs function on the entire tab-set, not just one tab. And ui.index needs to be replaced. If the 2nd panel has the id "tab2" then you can use:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
       if (ui.newPanel.selector == "#tab2") {
            alert("tab 2 selected");
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
/*tab placeholder*/.tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
       if(ui.item.id === "my-tab"){
           //explicitly trigger mouse click on tab
           $(ui.item).trigger('click');
       }
    }
});
//------------------
$("#my-tab").click(function(){
    alert('something')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `select` event has a `ui` parameter where you can check the `index` of the selected tab. This SO question has many examples: 
[jQuery UI Tabs Get Currently Selected Tab Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index)

You can then do the ajax call when you have checked the `index` of the tab.

EDIT: You also have many examples in the official Jquery UI doc here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs