# How to get currently selected tab index in jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, indexing

In jquery UI, using their newest version, I can't get the ID of the selected tab anymore. I tried `ui.index` from [jQuery UI Tabs Get Currently Selected Tab Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index), but it gives me undefined.

Does anyone know the way to do this now?

```
$( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsactivate", function(event, ui) { 
    alert(ui.index);
});
```

In this code, I get the alert every time I select a new tab, but its says undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use it this way. `ui` does not have any property called `index`

```
alert(ui.newTab.index());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gbXBn/)

1. Get the index of currently selected tab: `ui.newTab.index()`
2. Get the index of last selected tab: `ui.oldTab.index()`

`ui.newTab` will return you the jquery object representing the element and you can invoke the `index()` method on it to get the index.

Comment: am getting TypeError: ui.newTab.index() is undefined

Comment: How to get index of sub-tab ?