# JQuery-UI/JQuery tabs not refreshing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I have recently upgraded from jquery 1.4 to Jquery 1.10.1 and jquery-UI to version 1.10.3 and now my refresh tabs functionality is not working.

Here is what I had

```
$('#tabs').tabs('load', $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected'));
```

I have looked online for specific ways to achieve this using the versions I have with no luck and other exampes like using declaring the index dont seem t work.

I have stuck an alert on `$("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");` to what value it is getting and this is always `null` which indicated the problem is with this statement

Ho do you refresh jquery tabs in the versions I am using?

Comment: have you tried looking at the API Documentation? http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Take a look at the change log - often times, they will tell you what they replaced methods with. jQuery 1.10 is significantly different from 1.9 and immensely more from 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tab's **[.refresh()](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh)** method which was [added in 1.9](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#added-refresh-method).

> refresh()
>
> Process any tabs that were added or removed directly in the DOM and
>   recompute the height of the tab panels.

Ex:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
```

Comment: Won't this refresh all the tabs? I only want to refresh the one that is currently in focus

Answer (score 0):

The second answer to this question helped me fix the issue:

[jQuery UI Tabs Get Currently Selected Tab Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index)

In JQuery 1.9 the selected key word was changed to 'active'

```
$('#tabs').tabs('load', $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active'));
```