# Show callback is not firing jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I was following these example : http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/k6TEZ/ , in which is used the `callback` `show()`. 
I am executing this `callback` too , but it seems to not work. here it is my **html** and **jquery**

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu,mpus lectus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, d</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleife.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
```

**jquery**

```
 $("#tabs").tabs({
    show: function(event,ui){
        console.log("shown"+ui.index);
    }   
 });

$( "#tabs" ).find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
    axis: "x"
});

//tabsactivate
//tabsshow
 $('#tabs').on('tabsactivate', function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.newTab).data('index',ui.newTab.index());     
    console.log($(ui.newTab).data('index'),ui.newTab.index());
});
```

Can someone help me to undestand why `show()` is not firing?

with **jquery ui** 1.10 it is not working. With 1.9.2 it works.

Comment: just edited, I just noticed it.

Comment: According to the [changelog](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.10.0/), the show event is removed from tabs widget in 1.10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [jQuery UI 1.9 changelog](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.9.0/):

> Deprecated: show event; renamed to activate.

And according to the [jQuery UI 1.10 changelog](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.10.0/):

> Removed: show event.

Looks like you should use either [`activate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) or [`beforeActivate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate).

Comment: they have also changed how you get the index to `ui.newTab.index()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973370/74585