# Which jQuery UI tab got activated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I know there is an activate event on the jQuery tabs object, but what I don't know is how to check which tab fired the event. The documentation fails to mention this rather important aspect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Tabs Get Currently Selected Tab Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that even though I can hook up to an event, I still have to drill through the tabs object to find the selected tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the arguments in the callback is giving you a helping hand, and that is ui.newPanel.

Be aware though that the activate event is not getting called when the tabs get created and the first one displayed. There is another event for that. If you want to mix the two in a single callback, here is how you can achieve that in jQuery UI 1.10:

```
$(function () {    
    // prepare the events first
    $("#tabs").on("tabsactivate tabscreate", (event, ui) => {
        var panel = ui.newPanel || ui.panel;
        if (panel.is("#tabs-1")) {
            alert("first tab");
        } else if(panel.is("#tabs-2")){
            alert("second tab");
        }
    });

    //construct the tabs 
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Comment: Wow, I never imagined that "panel" actually means tab. Then again, I never knew an "is" function exists in jQuery. Very elegant solution. I hope it works.