# show/hide certain div on select of jQuery UI tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a working jQuery UI tabs, the structure is similarly like this:

```
<script>
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
</script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1"></a>Tab 1</li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2"></a>Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <!-- content of tab 1 -->
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <!-- content of tab 2 -->
  </div>
</div>
<div id="extra">
    <!-- some contents here -->
</div>
```

Now, I wanted to hide the div extra when **Tab 2** is selected, while showing it when **Tab 1** is selected. I can't quite understand the event thing on jQuery UI tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the [activate event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (e, ui) {
        $('#extra').toggle(ui.newPanel.is('#tabs-1'))
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bk9uL/)

Comment: Sorry, please see my edit the extra div is not inside the tabs div

Comment: @LeandroGarcia that doesn't change anything http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bk9uL/2/ also note that the tab header text should be within the anchor element like `<li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/cfnFk/**

See fiddle for everything but below is the js code...

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {
      alert(ui.newTab.index()); //tabs are a zero-based index, so Tab 1 = 0, Tab 2 = 1
      if(ui.newTab.index()===1) $( "#extra" ).hide();
      else $( "#extra" ).show();
  }
});
```

This is assuming you are using jQuery UI version 1.9 or later.  If not, read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/300221/3112803