# How to detect if #tabs-N is click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var isClicked = false;
$("a[href='#tabs-1']").off("click").on("click",function(){
    alert("tab 1 is click");    
    isClicked = true; // dont want to use like this.
});
```

I have this code when tab is click. My problem is how can i code like this to check tab is clicked?
i have this code snippet in mine.

```
if(#tabs-1' is clicked){ // do this}
```

Can someone point me out for solution. Also i do plan that having a boolean variable might help but im looking for jquery code to solve this(if there is).

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h64omf23/) for demo.

Comment: I think the fiddle is working?

Comment: `click` is an event not a state. You need to add an event handler to determine when it has been clicked.

Comment: @Mritunjay es sir, its working, but i want to add some logic conditioning if the tab-N is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
                console.log($(ui.tab)); // the tab selected
                alert(ui.index);
            }
});
```

[Check this solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/k6TEZ/672/)

Comment: In this  `ifselected="Tab 1 is selected"`` i can only used text? what if i needed to call some method or function when tab is click?

Comment: if (ui.index == 2) { // method }

Comment: Actually this is an excellent thread: [Get Currently Selected Tab Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index)

Answer (score 1):

If there is some custom data you need to access from each tab, you could just add an attribute and get it on `activate`:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li ifselected="Tab 1 is selected"><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li ifselected="Tab 2 is selected"><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li ifselected="Tab 3 is selected"><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
<!-- ... -->
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            alert($(ui.newTab).attr('ifselected'));
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3re1j5dL/)**.

**EDIT:

 Calling functions:**

```
$(function() {
    var tabfuncs = [
        () => alert("Tab 1 is selected"),
        () => alert("Tab 2 is selected"),
        () => alert("Tab 3 is selected")
    ];
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            tabfuncs[$(ui.newTab).index()]();
        }
    });
});
```

And another **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3re1j5dL/1/)**

Comment: In this `ifselected="Tab 1 is selected"`` i can only used text? what if i needed to call some method or function when tab is click?

Comment: Do you want to call the same method all of them, or have a separate method for each? If they are all separate, you could put your functions in an array, `var tabfuncs = [function() {}, function() {}]`, and call it with `tabfuncs[$(ui.newTab).index()]()`.

Answer (score 0):

how far i understand you want to put some logic after the tab is clicked and want to execute some logic over that then first of all you have to declare a **global string variable** instead of **local Boolean variable** that hold the id or title of the **#tab** like the below snippet

```
window.tabclicked = "";
```

then you have to assign the variable the id of the clicked tab like the following

```
 $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            $("a[href='#tabs-1']").off("click").on("click", function () {
                tabclicked = $(this).prop('href');
            });
        });
```

then you can use a switch statement for you condition

```
switch (tabclicked)
        {
            case "#tab1":
                {
                    // your logic here
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
```