# jQuery UI can't get selected tab outside of event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following HTML which I have applied Jquery tabs to:

```
<div id="lineitems">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#not-issued" onClick="displayItems()">Not Issued</a></li>
    <li><a href="#issued" onClick="displayItems()">Issued</a></li>
    <li><a href="#search" onClick="displayItems()">Search</a></li>
  </ul>

<div id="not-issued">Not Issued Items</div>
<div id="issued">Issued Items</div>
<div id="search">Search for items</div>

</div>
```

I have the following jQuery function which does what it's supposed to, it will return "issued" when you click on the issued tab etc.

```
$("#lineitems").tabs({
  beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
    var issued = ui.newPanel.attr('id'); //Get newly selected tab
    alert(issued);
  }
});

alert(issued);
```

The first `alert` correctly returns "issued" or whatever tab is selected, however the second `alert` returns `[object htmldivelement]`. I'm not sure why it isn't returning the same value. What am I doing wrong?

To put it into context, I'm trying to get the value of the selected tab so I can change the value of the submit button accordingly and then pass the value (of the selected tab) to an ajax function.

I have also tried using:

```
$("#lineitems").bind("tabsactivate", function(event, ui) {
    issued = ui.newTab.index();
    alert(issued);
});
```

But again I run into the same problem that the issued variable returns empty outside of the function.

**EDIT:** Using Bhushan Kawadkar's answer I got it working, I also had to change `issued` to a string using `toString()` to pass it to the Ajax function correctly.

I also followed T J's suggestion and removed the onClick event from my links as they're not needed, as the function is called every time a new tab is clicked anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Tabs Get Currently Selected Tab Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index)

Comment: I did try the suggestions on that question, and I get the same problem, still can't access the variable outside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare variable outside function to use it outside,
see below code

```
var issued = '';

$("#lineitems").tabs({
  beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
    issued = ui.newPanel.attr('id'); //Get newly selected tab
    alert(issued);
  }
});

alert(issued);
```

**Edit** - You are binding `tabs` and `bind` multiple time inside `displayItems()` function. Instead of this, you can bind it once inside `document.ready` or `$(function(){ ..});`. To pass `issued` value to `displayItems` function, call it inside `tabs` beforeActivate event.

jQuery :

```
$(function() { //This is in the <head> tag on my HTML
    $( "#lineitems" ).tabs();

    //Both of these methods work, but only inside the function
    $("#lineitems").bind("tabsactivate", function(event, ui) {
        var issued = ui.newTab.index();
        alert("bind "+issued);
    }); 

    $("#lineitems").tabs({
      beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        var issued = ui.newPanel.attr('id'); //Get newly selected tab
        alert("tabs "+issued);
        displayItems(issued);
      }
    });
});

function displayItems(issued)
{
    alert("display "+issued);
    //lineItems(job, issued); call to Ajax function
}
```

And remove `onclick="displayItems()"` from anchor tags.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/abt0tdbs/9/)**

Comment: when are you showing second alert? is this on load of page?

Comment: I'm showing it whenever the user selects a new tab, I call the function onClick of each tab

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Here is a JSfiddle link [jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abt0tdbs/). For some reason the `alert` isn't working, but you get the idea

Comment: *"call it inside tabs event"*? what tabs event..?

Comment: I meant tabs beforeActivate event

Answer (score 1):

- The reason why you ca't access the value outside is because you're
  storing it in a local variable.
- The reason why your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abt0tdbs/) is not working is becuase

  - The fiddle is set to run `onload` so the `displayItems` will be wrapped inside a `load` event handler hence won't be accessible outside
  - The following `var job = document.getElementById('joblist').value;` throws error becuase there is no elment with `id` `joblist`.

Ideally your code should be:

```js
$("#lineitems").tabs({
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
    },
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        issued = ui.newTab.index(); // issued is global so you can access it outside
        alert(issued);
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="lineitems">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#not-issued">Not Issued</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#issued">Issued</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#search">Search</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="not-issued">Not Issued Items</div>
    <div id="issued">Issued Items</div>
    <div id="search">Search for items</div>
</div>
```