# Selected tab id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following script which gets the index of the selected tab:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/eWncA/

Is it possible to get the id instead, if the li's had id's.  If it is easier to get it from elsewhere, then that would also be fine, i.e. the related div tags, or somewhere else.

Comment: I don't agree, posting links to jsfiddle allows users to quickly and easily make changes to the script, without having to re-create it on their own computer which would take longer for the person trying to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery UI just adds a class to the selected li.  You could just pull the li with the selected class out like this:

```
   var id = $("li.tab.ui-tabs-selected").attr("id");
```

If you wanted to get one of the unselected tabs you could do something like this:

```
var id = $("li.tab:not(.ui-tabs-selected)").first().attr("id");
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/UBs9m/2/

Comment: Your demo doesn't seem to work.  It seems to be returning the index.

Comment: I prefer Eugene's solution below because, although it is technically less efficient, it is not dependent on jQuery's default behavior and it shows the user how s/he can get the id of a non-selected tab for a different, future situation.

Comment: updated my jsfiddle link, also included a way to get a 'non-selected' tab in case that's a concern

Answer (score 4):

```
var id = $("li.tab:eq("+selected+")").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to simply use the Tabs control's `select` event handler, this works fine:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function( evt, ui ) {
        console.log( $(ui.panel).attr( 'id' ) );
    }
});
```

Also, here's [a handy reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185235/jquery-tabs-getting-newly-selected-index/185257#185257) for the different `ui` object properties.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery tabs (new version):

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li data-value="tab1"><a href="#tab1">Name of tab1</a></li>
            <li data-value="tab2"><a href="#tab2">Name of tab2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab1">
        </div>
        <div id="tab2">
        </div>
 </div>       

 //get id in init
 $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event ,ui) {
           var id = $(ui.newPanel).prop('id');
        }
      }
    );
 });
 var id = $("#tabs li.ui-state-active").attr('data-value'); //get id in other function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming here via Google like myself, and are using jQuery UI 1.9.X, use the `activate` or `beforeActivate` events to get the `id`:

```
$('selector').tabs({
  activate: function(e, ui) {
    var id = $(ui.newPanel).prop('id');
  }
});
```

#### [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)