# jquery ui tabs, do some css when specific tab is active, selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like to change some styling (for example body background color) when specific tab is selected (clicked) in jquery ui tabs.

Sth like:

```
if (tab nr 2 is selected) { $(body).css('background', 'red') }
if (tab nr 3 is selected) { $(body).css('background', 'blue') }
```

How can I check which tab is selected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185235/jquery-tabs-getting-newly-selected-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.ui-tabs-nav').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
     var index=ui.index;
     if(index===2){ 
        $(body).css('background', 'red')
     }
     else if(index===3){ 
        $(body).css('background', 'blue')
     }
 });
```

[Tab select documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select)

[Tabs Events documenation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#Events)

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-enable), you can use the event "enable" to keep track of this.

You could also do as such:

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
```

*(always from the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...retrieve_the_index_of_the_currently_selected_tab))*

Generally speaking, read the documentation, you'll find your answer there.